# Как сохранить в csv файл результат парсинга?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Знаю, что уже эту тему вдоль и поперек изучили тут, но все-таки, подскажите, пожалуйста, где в данном коде у меня ошибка. В json сохраняет, а в csv нет. Или выдает пустой файл или ошибку KeyError 'name'. Вот код:

```
with open('all_links.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
lines = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
companys = []

for line in lines:
    q = requests.get(line)
    result = q.content

    soup = BeautifulSoup(result, 'lxml')
    try:
        name = soup.find('h1', class_='detailPrimaryTitle').text
    except AttributeError:
        name = '-'
    try:
        web = soup.find('div', class_='detailBasicInfo').find(attrs={'data-dot':'show-website'}).get_text()
    except AttributeError:
        web = '-'
    try:
        phone1 = soup.find('div', class_='value detailPhone detailPhonePrimary').text
    except AttributeError:
        phone1 = '-'
    try:
        phone2 = soup.find('div', class_='value detailPhone noLabel').text
    except AttributeError:
        phone2 = '-'
    try:
        phone3 = soup.find('div', class_='value detailPhone').text
    except AttributeError:
        phone3 = '-'
    try:
        mail = soup.find('div', class_='value detailEmail').text
    except AttributeError:
        mail = '-'
    try:
        location = soup.find('div', class_='detailAddress').text
    except AttributeError:
        location = '-'
    try:
        ident_nmb = soup.find('div', class_='value detailBusinessInfo').text.split('Více')[0]
    except AttributeError:
        ident_nmb = '-'
    try:
        description = soup.find(class_='description').text
    except AttributeError:
        description = '-'

    company = {
            'name': name,
            'web': web,
            'phone1': phone1,
            'phone2': phone2,
            'phone3': phone3,
            'mail': mail,
            'location': location,
            'ident_nmb': ident_nmb,
            'description': description
    }

    companys.append(company)

    with open('companys.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
        writer.writerow(['Name', 'Web', 'Phone1', 'Phone2', 'Phone3', 'Mail', 'Location', 'Ident_nmb', 'Description'])
        writer.writerow(
            {soup['name'], soup['web'], soup['phone1'], soup['phone2'], soup['phone3'], soup['mail'], soup['location'],
             soup['ident_nmb'], soup['description']})
```

Comment: Дайте, пожалуйста, файл all_links.txt

Comment: https://www.firmy.cz/detail/12973177-aaa-auto-praha-cimice.html
https://www.firmy.cz/detail/12736819-mototechna-praha-cimice.html
https://www.firmy.cz/detail/13181207-autodraft-praha-vrsovice.html
https://www.firmy.cz/detail/13013525-davo-car-olbramovice-ves.html
https://www.firmy.cz/detail/205114-auto-jarov-praha-zizkov.html
https://www.firmy.cz/detail/205193-auto-esa-praha-sterboholy.html
и тд. 1500 ссылок. По отдельности из каждой все корректно достается. в json пишет. кажется мне, что в последнем блоке  что-то не так у меня. хотя ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предложу несколько модифицированную версию парсера, заодно и запись в csv слегка оптимизируем:

> `pip install pydantic bs4 requests`

all_links.txt

```
https://firmy.cz/detail/12973177-aaa-auto-praha-cimice.html
https://firmy.cz/detail/12736819-mototechna-praha-cimice.html
https://firmy.cz/detail/13181207-autodraft-praha-vrsovice.html
https://firmy.cz/detail/13013525-davo-car-olbramovice-ves.html
https://firmy.cz/detail/205114-auto-jarov-praha-zizkov.html
https://firmy.cz/detail/205193-auto-esa-praha-sterboholy.html
```

---

```py
import csv

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from requests import Session


class Company(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field('-', alias='Name')
    web: str = Field('-', alias='Web')
    phone1: str = Field('-', alias='Phone1')
    phone2: str = Field('-', alias='Phone2')
    phone3: str = Field('-', alias='Phone3')
    email: str = Field('-', alias='Email')
    location: str = Field('-', alias='Location')
    ident_nmb: str = Field('-', alias='Ident Number')
    description: str = Field('-', alias='Description')

    @classmethod
    def fields(cls):
        return list(cls.schema().get('properties').keys())


s = Session()


def parse(link: str):
    response = s.get(link)
    company = Company()

    soup = Soup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    if name_tg := soup.find('h1', class_='detailPrimaryTitle'):
        company.name = name_tg.get_text(strip=True)

    if (
            web_tg := soup.find('div', class_='detailBasicInfo')
    ) and (
            url_tg := web_tg.find(attrs={'data-dot': 'show-website'})
    ):
        company.web = url_tg.get_text(strip=True)

    if phone_tg := soup.find('div', class_='value detailPhone detailPhonePrimary'):
        company.phone1 = phone_tg.get_text(strip=True)

    if phone_tg := soup.find('div', class_='value detailPhone noLabel'):
        company.phone2 = phone_tg.get_text(strip=True)

    if phone_tg := soup.find('div', class_='value detailPhone'):
        company.phone3 = phone_tg.get_text(strip=True)

    if email_tg := soup.find('div', class_='value detailEmail'):
        company.email = email_tg.get_text(strip=True)

    if location_tg := soup.find('div', class_='detailAddress'):
        company.location = location_tg.get_text(strip=True)

    if ident_nmb_tg := soup.find('div', class_='value detailBusinessInfo'):
        company.ident_nmb, *_ = ident_nmb_tg.get_text(strip=True).split('Více')

    if description_tg := soup.find(class_='description'):
        company.description = description_tg.get_text(strip=True)

    return company


with open('all_links.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as url_file:
    with open('companies.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, dialect=csv.unix_dialect, fieldnames=Company.fields())
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(
            [
                item.dict(by_alias=True)
                for item in
                map(
                    parse,
                    filter(
                        None,
                        url_file.read().split()
                    )
                )
            ]
        )
```

---

companies.csv

```
"Name","Web","Phone1","Phone2","Phone3","Email","Location","Ident Number","Description"
"AAA AUTO","www.aaaauto.cz","+420 800 400 450","-","-","obchod@aaaauto.cz","Dopraváků 874/15, 184 00  Praha, Čimice","01759299","Nepřekonatelný výběr, výhodné ceny, široké garance a výhodné možnosti financování. Přes 12 000 kvalitních a prověřených aut. Až 36 měsíců garance na mechanický stav vozu, kontrola najetých km. Doživotní záruka legálního původu. Výkup všech modelů a značek, férové ceny, peníze ihned a v hotovosti."
"Mototechna","www.mototechna.cz","+420 800 121 111","-","-","obchod@mototechna.cz","Dopraváků 874/15, 184 00  Praha, Čimice","26194716","Koupí vozu od nás ušetříte až 40 % vůči ceně nového vozu. Specializujeme se na zánovní a předváděcí vozy se zárukou. Až 2000 aut různých značek a modelů ihned k odběru. Kvalitní záruční a pozáruční servis a autorizovaný servis vozidel Škoda."
"Autodraft","www.autodraft.cz","+420 735 127 096","+420 731 482 686","+420 736 244 732","prodej@autodraft.cz","Pod soutratím 1559/5, 101 00  Praha, Vršovice","04958250","Nabízíme Passaty, Superby a Oktávky v Česku. Ve výbavách a barvách, které se jen tak nevidí. Vybrané tak pečlivě, že vy už nemůžete udělat chybu. A vybavené dvouletou zárukou na cesty. Kupte si vaše další auto online. Bez stresu. V Autodraftu."
"DAVO CAR","www.davocar.cz","+420 739 343 434","+420 739 343 433","-","info@davocar.cz","Olbramovice Ves 203, 259 01","27934799","Na prodejní ploše autobazaru o rozloze 80.000 m2 nabízíme až 1000 s financování o 0% akontace. Poskytujeme výkup vozů všech značek, peníze vyplácíme ihned a v hotovosti. Poskytujeme garanci na původ vozu a stav tachometru. Nabízíme záruku až na 36 měsíců na mechanické a elektronické součástky vozu."
"AUTO JAROV","www.autojarov.cz","+420 251 002 111","+420 251 002 222","-","autojarov@autojarov.cz","Osiková 2688/2, 130 00  Praha, Žižkov","45789584","2000 vozů skladem ihned k odběru. Autorizovaný prodej a servis značek Volkswagen, ŠKODA, Audi, SEAT, CUPRA, Honda a s autosalonem zánovních vozů. Moderní servisní zázemí. Výkup vozidel. Operativní leasing za zajímavé ceny. Kompletní služby pod jednou střechou."
"Auto ESA","autoesa.cz","+420 800 555 555","-","+420 221 410 310","zakaznickecentrum@autoesa.cz","K Učilišti 170, 102 00  Praha, Štěrboholy","25627538","Certifikovaný prodejce, výhodné ceny a bohatý výběr z více než 6000 prověřených osobních i užitkových vozů. Garance kontroly km a původu, výhodné financování, splátky bez navýšení a záruka na technický stav. Individuální přístup k zákazníkům a vysoké výkupní ceny v hotovosti ihned na ruku."
```

##### Что касается ошибок у Вас:

```py
# У Вас
with open('all_links.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
lines = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
# Должно быть
with open('all_links.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
```

---

```py
# У Вас 
# По сути Вы каждым проходом цикла перезаписываете csv файл
    companys.append(company)

    with open('companys.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
        writer.writerow(['Name', 'Web', 'Phone1', 'Phone2', 'Phone3', 'Mail', 'Location', 'Ident_nmb', 'Description'])

    # Я бы не использовал в данном случае множество, 
    # поскольку порядок элементов в множестве не может быть определен
        writer.writerow(
            {soup['name'], soup['web'], soup['phone1'], soup['phone2'], soup['phone3'], soup['mail'], soup['location'],
             soup['ident_nmb'], soup['description']})

# Должно быть
    companys.append(company)

with open('companys.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
    writer.writerow(['Name', 'Web', 'Phone1', 'Phone2', 'Phone3', 'Mail', 'Location', 'Ident_nmb', 'Description'])
    writer.writerow(
        [
            soup['name'], soup['web'], soup['phone1'], soup['phone2'], soup['phone3'], soup['mail'], soup['location'],
         soup['ident_nmb'], soup['description']
        ])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

lines = ['https://en.firmy.cz/detail/13181207-autodraft-praha-vrsovice.html',
         'https://en.firmy.cz/company/205114-auto-jarov-praha-zizkov.html']
with open('companys.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
    writer.writerow(['Name', 'Web', 'Phone'])

    for line in lines:
        response = requests.get(line)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
        name = soup.find('h1').text
        phone = [x.text for x in soup.find_all(attrs={'data-dot': 'origin-phone-number'})]
        web = [x.text for x in soup.find_all('a', {"class": "value"})]
        writer.writerow([name, '\n'.join(web), '\n'.join(phone)])
```